# How to properly recieve data from list of forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create a `Quiz` in Django. There are multiple questions and `QuestionForm`. In a view, I get set of `Questions` and create a list of `QuestionForm`s for each object. Then this list is sent into the template and render text and form for each question separately.

This way is very uncomfortable and I think that there must be a more simple and straightforward way to do that.

The main flow:

When user takes a test, the `Sitting` object is created. This object holds information about user, quiz and preloaded questions. When user answeres the quiz, there is created `SittingQuestion` objects which holds information about question and user answer.

As you can see, I've added a parameter `name = question-id` for each form and the result of each form is `answer-id`. I have to parse id's and create  object's using this id's.

I would appreciate any help to avoid parsing especially.

I'm attaching a `QuestionForm` and a `view`:

**QuestionForm**

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, question, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choice_list = [(x.pk, x.text) for x in question.get_answers_list()]
        self.fields["question-{}".format(question.id)] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice_list,
                                                   widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

**View**

```
def take_quiz(request, id):
    if request.method == 'GET':

        sitting = models.Sitting.objects.create(quiz=quiz, user=request.user)
        sitting.load_questions()
        formset = []
        for q in sitting.sitting_questions.all():
            formset.append((q.question, forms.QuestionForm(q.question)))

        return render(request, 'quiz/quiz.html', context={'formset': formset})

    quiz = get_object_or_404(models.LanguageQuiz, pk=id)
    sitting = get_object_or_404(Sitting,user=request.user,quiz=quiz)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for question in request.POST:
            question_id = question.split('-')[1]
            question_object = get_object_or_404(Question,id=question_id)
            answer_id = request.POST[question_id][0]
            answer_object = get_object_or_404(Answer,id=answer_id)
            SittingQuestion.objects.create(sitting=sitting,question=question_object,answer=answer_object)
```

**MODELS**

```
class LanguageQuiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    language = models.OneToOneField(sfl_models.Language)
    max_questions = models.IntegerField()
    time_to_repeat_in_days = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} test'.format(self.name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.__str__()

class Question(models.Model):
    language_quiz = models.ForeignKey(LanguageQuiz,related_name='questions')
    text = models.TextField()

    def get_answers_list(self):
        return self.answers.all()

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,related_name='answers',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    correct = models.BooleanField()

class Sitting(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(sfl_models.User, related_name='test_sitting')
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(LanguageQuiz)
    date_opened = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_closed = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user','quiz')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Sitting - user: {}; quiz: {}'.format(self.user, self.quiz)

    def load_questions(self):
        questions = random.sample(self.quiz.questions.all(),min(self.quiz.max_questions,len(self.quiz.questions.all())))
        for question in questions:
            SittingQuestion.objects.create(question=question,sitting=self)

class SittingQuestion(models.Model):
    sitting = models.ForeignKey(Sitting, related_name='sitting_questions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='sitting_questions')
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer,null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible improvement to the design:

Instead of `QuestionForm`, make a `QuizForm`. Pass `sitting.sitting_questions.all()` to your form, and make each one its own `ChoiceField`. This will make it much easier to process your form. Once you initialize whatever variables you need, handling in the view is usually as simple as this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = QuizForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # whatever you'd like to do
else:               # GET
    form = QuizForm(list_of_questions)
```

There is no need to parse to get the `question id`, you can just call `question.id` or `question.pk`.

some elaboration:

```
class QuizForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, questions, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuizForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for question in questions:
            choice_list = [("QUESTION TEXT", question.text)]
            choice_list.append([(x.pk, x.text) for x in question.get_answers_list()])
            self.fields["question-{}".format(question.id) = forms.ChoiceField(
                choices=choice_list,
                widget=forms.RadioSelect
             )
```

Update: How to add Question text before options.

If your QuizForm has fields which are all questions, then when you iterate over your field you will get these question fields: `{% for question in form %}`. Since `question` is a field and not the actual `Question` object, I admit you can't simply access `question.text` in the loop. However, you can decide to add `question.text` to the choices field (a little hack-ish, but functional), I've included this possibility above. Then try something like this:

```
{% for question in form %}
{% for id, text in question.field.choices %}
{% if id == 'QUESTION TEXT' %}
    {{ text }}
{% else %}
    <!-- render however you like -->
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

For rendering buttons: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect
I think there are a lot of similar questions on SO already for how to render the choices.

Comment: Thanks but thats the problem. I cant figure out how to create question forms inside quiz form. Could you elaborate it please?

Comment: Have you tried a for loop? for question in questions: choice_list =... and self.fields... = forms.ChoiceField...?

Also, the questions shouldn't be forms, they should be form fields of the quiz form.

Comment: Yeah this is nice but one more thing. I can't figure out how to put the text for each question before the radioselects. I can iterate over QuizForm like {% for answers in form %} {{ form }} {% endfor %} which renders radiobuttons of sets of answers but there is no way how to put there a text of the question before each set. I've tried {% for....%} {{ answer.question.text }} etc. but nothing seems working...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but I'll update my post to try to help you get started in the right direction.